# java thread code flow

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm really puzzled by the following pieces of code :

```java
@Component
public class DrawingFileExplorer {

    private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        public void explore(File drawingFolder) throws InterruptedException {       
            for(File each : drawingFolder.listFiles(DrawingFileFilter.getInstance())) {
                if(each.isDirectory()) {
                    explore(each);
                } else {
                    //pool.execute(new DrawingFileReviewer(each));
                }
            }
            System.out.println("THIS LINE OF CODE SHOULD BE INVOKED ONCE");

            pool.shutdown();
            pool.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

}

// Trigger of DrawingFileExplorer
public class DrawingFileExplorerTest {

    private static File baseFolder = new File("C:\\Users\\Jake\\Desktop\\baseFolder\\02. Current Drawings");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");
        DrawingFileExplorer drawingFileExplorer = (DrawingFileExplorer) ctx.getBean("drawingFileExplorer");
        drawingFileExplorer.explore(baseFolder);
    }

}
```

As of i know the line System.out.println(..) after foreach should be invoked only once.
but the output of the code is following.

```
THIS LINE OF CODE SHOULD BE INVOKED ONCE
THIS LINE OF CODE SHOULD BE INVOKED ONCE
```

Could anyone explain how it can be invoked twice?
my thread between first output and second line of output are not executed due to the shutdown().

Comment: explore is calling itself.

Comment: sound like very trivial question after hearing answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a recursive call after checking if `each` is a directory, that is -

```
 if(each.isDirectory()) {
   explore(each); // <-- HERE
```

So you will get multiple(s) of your line if (and only if) there are sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is recursive, so why do you expect it not to be called over and over (once for every directory)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `explore` is recursive method, which can be invoked even multiple times based on number of directories.

```
for(File each : drawingFolder.listFiles(DrawingFileFilter.getInstance())) {
                if(each.isDirectory()) {
                    explore(each);  // this call is inside for loop and will be invoke recursively.
                } else {
                    //pool.execute(new DrawingFileReviewer(each));
                }
            }
```

For eg, given directory structure will print the line for 5 times,

> DraginFolder
>
> SubFolder1
>
> ```
>   SubFolder2
> ```
>
> SubFolder3
>
> SubFolder4

Answer (score 0):

You have to move

```
System.out.println("THIS LINE OF CODE SHOULD BE INVOKED ONCE");
pool.shutdown();
pool.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

outside of `explore`

When the code executed on a directory only contain files, the above 3 lines code will be executed. And because you shutdown the pool, you will cannot explore all files.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class DrawingFileExplorer {

    private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public void explore(File drawingFolder) throws InterruptedException {   
        _explore(drawingFolder);

        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void _explore(File drawingFolder) {
        for(File each : drawingFolder.listFiles(DrawingFileFilter.getInstance())) {
            if(each.isDirectory()) {
                _explore(each);
            } else {
                pool.execute(new DrawingFileReviewer(each));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

made another _explorer(..) method to solve it thanks.